# Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, handler

I have a DelegatingHandler in my web API for authentification (HMAC).

I would like to add a GET parameter to the request to return the user's id to my controller.

In my handler, I tried adding it like so:

```
public class SecurityHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string apikey = request.Headers.GetValues(AuthConfig.ApiKeyHeader).First();
        UserDTO user = UserRepo.GetUser(apikey);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return SendResponseText("Invalid API key");
        }

        // Validate signature ...

        // Add user Id to the URI
        request.RequestUri = new Uri(request.RequestUri.OriginalString + "&UserId=" + user.Id);
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

In my controller, I'm able to get the newly added parameter from the request uri, however the **parameter binding is not working**

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    ...
}

public string Get([FromUri] MyModel model)
{
    // model.UserId has not been set (= 0)
    // Request.RequestUri contains "&UserId=5"
}
```

**Update**

I'm guessing the binding is being done from the Params in the HttpContext. I tried something like this, but Params collection is readonly.

```
var newContext = request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"] as HttpContextWrapper;
newContext.Request.Params.Add("UserId", "8");
request.Properties.Remove("MS_HttpContext");
request.Properties.Add("MS_HttpContext", newContext);
```

Comment: If UserId is your first parameter, it should has ? instead of &

    request.RequestUri = new Uri(request.RequestUri.OriginalString + "?UserId=5";

Comment: It is not my first parameter

Comment: It seems that you did not check my last update that I made more than 8 hours ago

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have tried at my side and it working.

Here is my sample url.

```
http://localhost:50382/api/values?UserId=10
```

Here is controller action.

```
public class ValueController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Get([FromUri]Model my)
            {
                return new string[] { "value1", "value2" , my.UserId.ToString() };
            }
}
```

As per your comment here I created delegate handler.

```
  public class MyMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
  {
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
            HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var myTempObj = new { id = 20 };
      /* You have to check this and remove this key. If key present that FromUri use cached properties*/
        if (request.Properties.ContainsKey("MS_QueryNameValuePairs"))
        {
            request.Properties.Remove("MS_QueryNameValuePairs");                
        }

        // Now prepare or update uri over here. It will surely work now.
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.RequestUri.Query) && request.RequestUri.Query.Contains('?'))
            {
                request.RequestUri = new Uri(request.RequestUri + "&UserID=" + myTempObj.id);
            }
            else
            {
                request.RequestUri = new Uri(request.RequestUri + "?UserID=" + myTempObj.id);
            }    

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

It is work as expected.

If your original request contain userid then it get duplicated and it will not work. It return 0.

I also have doubt that you are using request.RequestUri.OriginalString. Just try to use request.RequestUri. It might possible that OriginalString has encoded value.

Comment: In my case I want to add a new parameter to the current request in my delegating handler.

Comment: So once request comes you modify RequestUrl in your custom delegate handler. Is this you are doing ?

Comment: Your example is similar to mine, tried it anyway but it doesn't not work. Did you actually get this to work ? I'm running on framework 4.0 by the way.

Comment: Yes. It is working example. Did you try my handler ? I can only see problem  with your URL.

Comment: For some reason this only works if the original URI does not contain any parameters. If I add a parameter to the URI (eg. http://localhost:1234/api/forum?Product=10), then the binding of the UserId added in the handler does not work :(

Comment: I think you are getting 0 value instead of value. This can happen if your original uri also contain userid. Like  localhost:1234/api/forum?Product=10&userid=20 and one added in hanlder. If it get duplicate then it will return 0. Do you have any other message handler? Please see my answer again for last few comment.

Comment: The original URI does not contain the parameter, have also tried with RequestUri instead or OriginalString. Please have a look at this [sample project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwh7_S7dH8_ZS1JCX2JsTmo1ZXc/view?usp=sharing) if you have the time, I would really appreciate it ;)

Answer (score 1):

I found the following solution to my problem

```
request.RequestUri = new Uri(request.RequestUri + "&UserId=8");

var newFormDataCollection = new FormDataCollection(request.RequestUri);
request.Properties.Remove("MS_QueryNameValuePairs");
request.Properties.Add("MS_QueryNameValuePairs", newFormDataCollection);

return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
```

`[FromURI]` seems to use the values in the FormDataCollection, so you simply need to update the "MS_QueryNameValuePairs" property.

Comment: My update somewhat similar and more than 8 hours ago

Comment: Indeed, I did not get a notification of you edits. Thank you for your help ;)